# Blog Posts in Custom Menu

Tags: posts, customization, menus, blog

I have a custom menu but would like to put specific posts on each one. 
for example: my menu consists of: cooking, beauty and style. How can i put all cooking posts on the cooking tab, and all beauty on the beauty tab and etc? I just want my viewers to be able to click on that tab and get all of the content for it and not have to go to the tab and get a drop down menu of other posts.

Comment: So you would like to list the top 5 or so posts underneath a menu entry? Showing all posts will not scale and will have performance and UI issues

Answer (score 1):

I am little bit unsure, if this could really be an answer :-) But I think, you can simply create categories - Cooking, Beauty, Style. Assign those categories to respective posts. Then add these categories as menus. Now, when user clicks on any of the menu, he will see posts belonging to the respective category. Please take a [look at this tutorial](https://en.support.wordpress.com/category-pages/). UI could be different but it very well addresses what you are trying to achieve and what I am trying to say.